# Securely provide a one-liner bash install script

Tags: bash, shell, curl, wget

I like to provide one-line bash install scripts for things, that look something like this:

```
curl https://gist.githubusercontent.com/.../raw/install.sh | bash
```

or even

```
curl http://tinyurl.com/installmything | bash
```

But that's obviously a massive security risk for anyone that doesn't trust me.

Is there any convenient, simple way that would:

1. let the user view the script before it runs,
2. still only requires a single copy-paste operation
3. isn't excessively cumbersome?

For example, I could provide the one-liner like this:

```
wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/.../installthing.sh ; cat installthing.sh ; read -p "Type YES to continue: " X && [ $X = "YES" ] && bash installthing.sh
```

That fails the cumbersomeness requirement. Any better ways?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two types of people who don't trust you:

1. Who know bash: These people will download your script anyway and view its content. They understand what `curl ... | bash` does and they won't execute that command.
2. Who don't know bash: Even if you show the source code to these people, they won't be able to do anything with that. They won't be able to decide whether that code is a security risk or not.

So I think it's not needed to let the user view the content of the script before execution. But if you still want it, you could for example run the script, but ask the user before the real code gets executed. Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Do you wish to see the content of this script before execution?" -n 1 -r
echo

if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
then
  tail -n +20 "$0"

  echo
  read -p "Continue? " -n 1 -r
  echo

  if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Nn]$ ]]
  then
    exit
  fi
fi

echo "INSTALL"
```

This way you can keep using:

```
curl https://gist.githubusercontent.com/.../raw/install.sh | bash
```

Comment: Oh, that's an interesting analysis. So I could include a comment with the one-liner like, "The code for the script will be shown before execution, which you can easily verify."

Comment: You have to quote ``"$0"``. Also there is no need for regex, you can simply do ``[[ ${REPLY^} == 'Y' ]]``

Comment: +10 if I could. Simply, if someone understand shell and want analyse the script, will download it for check. For others is pointless to show its content. BTW, the "dialog" can break the install procedure for example if someone adding it to another bash script - so, need check it the script is attached to terminal - too much complications what not worths.

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko Thanks! Added the quotes around `$0`. Didn't touch the rest as this is just an example, many things could be improved in this script.